# Improve training performance for the Back Propagation Network for the following matlab code

Tags: matlab, neural-network

When I run the following code

```
     input=[0 0; 0 1; 1 0; 1 1];  % OR example

     input=transpose(input);
     target=[0;1;1;1];

     target=transpose(target);

     net=newff(input,target,5,{'logsig','logsig'});

     net=train(net,input,target);

     result=sim(net,input);

     % result is like this

     %0.5000 1.000 1.000 1.000

     %but want my output as 

     %0 1 1 1
```

When I see the performance of the network it is **0.125**. But i want it to be **0.0001**. Even when try to decrease the goal to 1e-30 the performance does not decrease, instead it increases. Please give me a solution to improve the performance of this network, as this is only a sample code, with the help of this i need to build a large network with 419 inputs and 2 outputs.

Please clear my doubt.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: I am using MATLAB version 2010a

Comment: See my answer below. Does that help fix the problem?

Answer (score 3):

### MATLAB Solution

The problem lies in your chosen hidden and output layer membership function, `logsig`, and your chosen input and target range `[0, 1]`. If you go to MATLAB and type `logsig(0)`, you will get an answer of `0.5`. Basically by making both your hidden layer and your output layer use `logsig`, you end up getting a very small number out of your hidden layer for the `False` case (an input of `[0 0]`), which in turn gives you a network output of `logsig(0) = 0.5`. There are two ways around this.

#### First Method

Use `purelin` for your output layer, and add a few extra training examples by duplicating the existing training examples that you are using. This ensures that your output is a linear combination of the outputs of your hidden layer:

```
input = repmat(input, 1, 5);          % make more input data
target = repmat(target, 1, 5);        % make more target data
net = newff(input, target, 5, {'logsig', 'purelin'});    % note the output tf 'purelin'
% Proceed as before.
```

Now when you pass `[0 0]` into your hidden layer, you will get a very small number out of your hidden layer, and the linear combination of these small numbers will give you something close to `0`.

#### Second Method

Scale all of your inputs and targets to the `[-1, 1]` range instead of the `[0, 1]` range. This will basically ensure that the training function can use the full range of `logsig` in training, instead of just the upper half as before. Now, just like above, you need to make some extra data to train with:

```
input = [-1 -1; -1 1; 1 -1; 1 1]';    % note the apostrophe (') takes the transpose of the matrix
target = [-1 1 1 1];                  % no transpose needed
input = repmat(input, 1, 5);          % make more input data
target = repmat(target, 1, 5);        % make more target data
net = newff(input, target, 5, {'logsig', 'logsig'});    % note the output tf 'logsig'
% Proceed as before.
```

Both of these methods got me the results that I was looking for.

**Note:** In general, just copying your data is not enough to increase the size of your data set. I believe it works in this case because your data set encompasses the entire population of possible inputs to an **OR** circuit. In general, you need to do more than just copy as this can cause overfitting. What you have to do depends on what type of data you are using. For example, if you were doing image recognition, you could add distortions to the images: enlarge parts, skew images, etc., but not random noise. The idea is to emulate "real life" examples.

### Octave Solution (seems to be more intuitive)

If you have Octave, which is basically a free and open-source version of MATLAB, you can generate the desired network using the `nnet` package as below. Note that the `nnet` package uses the previous (discontinued) MATLAB syntax of defining a matrix of the ranges of each input (`Pr`), and then a vector of the number of nodes in each layer (`Ss`).

```
Pr = [0 1; 0 1];
Ss = [2 5 1];
net = newff(Pr, Ss, {'purelin', 'logsig', 'purelin'});
net = train(net, input, target);
result = sim(net, input)
```

I used your original input and target vectors in the `[0 1]` range, and ended up with a result of `[-1.7e-16, 1, 1, 1]` which is really darn close to the `[0 1 1 1]` that we are expecting to get.